# When do we add error handling code in a program?

Tags: python, sockets, error-handling

I learned how to add error handling. But I am little bit confused about when we need to add it to my code.
See this following example.
Do I need error handling for every line of calling the socket?

Server.py

```
import socket
sockfd = socket.socket()
try:
   sockfd.bind(("127.0.0.1", 20001))
except socket.error as emsg:
   print("Socket bind error: ", emsg)
   sys.exit(1)
print("I_am", socket.gethostname(), "and_I_am_listening_...")
sockfd.listen(5)
new, who = sockfd.accept() # Return the TCP connection
print("A_connection_with", who, "has_been_established")
try:
   message = new.recv(50)
except socket.error as err:
   print("Recv error: ", err)
if message:
   print("\'"+message.decode("ascii")+"\'", "is received from", who)
else:
   print("Connection is broken")
new.close()
sockfd.close()
```

Comment: If you want to change what happens when something goes wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One commonly used approach to error handling is to add it when there is a possibility for something unexpected to happen, i.e. something that you did not expect when writing the code. This means that if you have e.g. a simple function whose different possible error states you know, that is when you do not need to add try-statements since you can handle the errors with e.g. if-else statements. This also usually reduces memory consumption, since try-block has a bigger overhead. But in case there are things that you do not know or have no control over, e.g. external program returns or API calls, that is when you should add error handling.